# Svelte store - all submitted array values get updated instead of one value

Tags: typescript, svelte, sveltekit

I am struggling to get my head around how to use stores, I am using a svelte store to create a simple todo array with prepopulated dummy data. I then want to use the store within the todo component displaying the dummy data and then updating when the user submits new data.

Now i can update the svelte store array, but when the user then adds another todo item it also updates the previously submitted value.

I have an interface entity called `todo.ts` which is implemented in the `todo-store.ts` i then access the store within the `+page.svelte` and create a todo object to the hold the form data called `todoItem` i then pass this to the store when the submit button is pressed

**`Todo.ts`**

```
export interface ITodoItem {
    id: string;
    text: string;
    completed: boolean;
}
```

**`todo-store.ts`**

```
import { writable } from 'svelte/store';
import type { ITodoItem } from '../../entities/todo';

const todos: ITodoItem[] = [
    { id: '1', text: 'Todo 1', completed: true },
    { id: '2', text: 'Todo 2', completed: false },
    { id: '3', text: 'Todo 3', completed: false },
    { id: '4', text: 'Todo 4', completed: false },
  ]

export const todoList = writable<ITodoItem[]>(todos);
```

**`+page.svelte`**

```
<script lang="ts">
    import { todoList } from './todo-store';
    import type { ITodoItem } from '../../entities/todo';

    let todoItem = <ITodoItem>{
        id: '',
        text: '',
        completed: false
    };

    const addToList = () => {
        $todoList = [...$todoList, todoItem];
    };
</script>

<h1>Todo List</h1>

<form on:submit|preventDefault={addToList}>
    <div>
        Id:<input type="text" id="id" bind:value={todoItem.id} />
    </div>
    <div>
        Todo:<input type="text" id="name" bind:value={todoItem.text} />
    </div>
    <div>
        <button>Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>

<hr />
{#each $todoList as item}
    <ul>
        <li>
            {item.text}
        </li>
    </ul>
{/each}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, that you add a [*reference*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language) to the item to the list, so whenever you add an item, you actually add the same item over and over.

The fix is to copy the item when adding it, here a [shallow copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184710/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deep-copy-and-a-shallow-copy) is enough, which can be done by spreading the properties:

```js
const addToList = () => {
    const newItem = { ...todoItem };
    $todoList = [...$todoList, newItem];
};
```

If you need a deep copy, you might want to use something like [`structuredClone`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/structuredClone).